# Apple Music: "Uploaded" vs. "matched" songs on iCloud Music Library

Tags: itunes, apple-music

I just subscribed to Apple Music and I decided to upload all the songs I had in my Mac's iTunes library to the iCloud Music Library.
Some songs have been labeled as `uploaded`, meaning that Apple has scanned and uploaded this track from my library to its servers, but it didn't match it with any songs in its database. Some other songs are marked as `matched`, meaning that Apple has scanned and matched the track in my Mac's library with a song in its iTunes Store catalog.

My question is: is it possible to *manually* merge one of the "just uploaded" songs with their corresponding matches in the iTunes Store catalog? One option could be re-downloading the song and re-adding it to the library, but in this case I will lose all the meta information of the original song (in particular the number of times I played the song). 
Are there any other workarounds to solve the problem?

Comment: This also makes me very sad :( Particularly my entire TOOL catalogue - seems like none of it matched :/